# I need to read a CSV file and split them into different arrays for each column

Tags: c#, windows, csv

I have a very large data file with around 60000 rows. I need to split the CSV file based on columns into different arrays for each column.

I have 5 columns; `State, County, Zipcode, Latitude, Longitude`.

How would I, when I read the file, split it and add them in order to each array?

I would have an array for `State, County, Zipcode, Latitude`, and `Longitude`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CSV parser - there are plenty for .NET, even a built in one in the `VisualBasic` namespace.

See [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) - though in the `VisualBasic` namespace, it is a regular .NET library that can be used by any .NET language.

There are [many](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) [other](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86973/C-CSV-Reader-and-Writer) [options](http://www.filehelpers.com/).

Comment: Would this separate each column and put every value from each column into different arrays?

Comment: @AdamAndre - It _could_. Though I would normally create a type to hold the data and use a generic collection of the type in order to have the data in a meaningful and strongly typed container.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it manually (i would also recommend to use `TextFieldParser`), you could use a `StreamReader` to loop all lines and use `String.Split` to split by your separator(assuming comma):

```
var stateList = new List<String>();
var countyList = new List<String>();
var zipCodeList = new List<String>();
var latitudeList = new List<String>();
var longitudeList = new List<String>();

using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\csv.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var fields = line.Split(new Char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        stateList.Add(fields[0]);
        if (fields.Length > 1)
            countyList.Add(fields[1]);
        if (fields.Length > 2)
            zipCodeList.Add(fields[2]);
        if (fields.Length > 3)
            latitudeList.Add(fields[3]);
        if (fields.Length > 4)
            longitudeList.Add(fields[4]);
    }
}
```

If you really need an Array instead of a List:

```
String[] states = stateList.ToArray();
String[] counties = countyList.ToArray();
String[] zipCodes = zipCodeList.ToArray();
String[] latitudes = latitudeList.ToArray();
String[] longitudes = longitudeList.ToArray();
```